# 400 Error "Invalid request body" on HTTP POST in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, http, httprequest

I've been tasked with doing an HTTP POST in Excel VBA. I have an HTTP GET that's working fine in the same context.

First, here's the HTTP GET that's working fine in this context, with names generalized:

```
Set httpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
MyApiUrl = "https://MyServer/MyFolder/MySearchAPI?MyParamName1=MyParamValue1&MyParamName2=MyParamValue2"
httpRequest.Open "GET", MyApiUrl, False
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "my-api-key", "my api key value"
httpRequest.send
```

Here's everything I've been told to get this HTTP POST working:

First, the name of the API is MyUpdateAPI. The URL path to it is the same:
https://MyServer/MyFolder/MyUpdateAPI

Second, the parameters (in XLM format?) are as follows, again with names generalized:

```
{
    "MyParamName1": MyParamValue1,
    "MyParamName2": "MyParamValue2",
    "MyParamName3": MyParamValue3,
    "MyParamName4": "MyParamValue4",
    "MyParamParentName": {
        "MyParamChildName1": "MyParamChildValue1",
        "MyParamChildName2": "MyParamChildValue2"
    }
}
```

Some coworkers have a test tool that they paste that XML into and it returns 200, success.

I don't know how to form the XML parent/child params into HTTP parameters.

Using the sample HTTP POST in Excel VBA at https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/ as a guide, here's what I've tried:

```
'build params:
MyParam1 = "MyParamName1=MyParamValue1" '(no ampersand on the first param).
MyParam2 = "&MyParamName2=MyParamValue2"
MyParam3 = "&MyParamName3=MyParamValue3"
MyParam4 = "&MyParamName4=MyParamValue4"
MyParamChild1 = "&MyParamChildName1=MyParamChildName1"
MyParamChild2 = "&MyParamChildName2=MyParamChildName2"
sAllParams = MyParam1 & MyParam2 & MyParam3 & MyParam4 & MyParamChild1 & MyParamChild2

Set httpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
MyApiUrl = "https://MyServer/MyFolder/MyUpdateAPI"

httpRequest.Open "POST", MyApiUrl, False
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "my-api-key", "my api key value"
httpRequest.send sAllParams
```

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong? How should the XML parent/child params be formatted in the HTTP parameter string?

Comment: Ask your coworkers for a working curl call for this. From that you should be able to recreate your call. Some header is likely missing

Comment: Here, `sAllParams` has typically a syntax adequate for an URL. It has not a JSON format. Note JSON is not XML. It is a different generic format.

Comment: How/where are the parameter values set ? What type are they numeric, string, date ?

Comment: @Sam, thanks, I'll try. I've already asked them for examples of using the apis in other programming languages, but apparently none exist. They seem to think I should be able to just paste the XML in VBA as is and run it.

Comment: @FrédéricLOYER, thanks, the return value of the MySearchAPI HTTP GET is in JSON format, which I guess is the reason for the JSON header. Maybe I should remove that header for this HTTP POST?

Comment: @CDP1802, the parameter values are all samples they have given me. Some are text, some look like numbers. For the MySearachAPI HTTP GET that is working fine, both look like numbers but are typed as string.

Comment: "Content Type" header tells the server *what type of content you are sending in the request body* so in this case since you're sending JSON, you should leave the header as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
    Dim data
   ' some test data
   data = Array(, 1, "A", 2, "B", "C", "D")
   
   Dim sAllParams As String
   sAllParams = "{'MyParamName1':" & data(1) & _
    ",'MyParamName2': '" & data(2) & _
    "','MyParamName3': " & data(3) & _
    ",'MyParaName4': '" & data(4) & _
    "','MyParamParentName': {" & _
    "'MyParamChildName1':'" & data(5) & _
    "','MyParamChildName2':'" & data(6) & _
    "'}}"
    sAllParams = Replace(sAllParams, "'", """")
    
    Debug.Print sAllParams

    httpRequest.send sAllParams
```

Comment: Thanks--that's returning 200/success though not updating My ParamChild2. Working with my coworkers on that now..

Comment: Well, there was a meeting today where our API devs decided that these API functions weren't suitable for our team, and they're going to write new ones for us. So I'm going to mark this as the answer. Thanks!